# Set multiple Word text box to fit text at once (batch)

Tags: microsoft-word

In Word (2010), how can I set multiple text boxes to fit text without having to click each individually? There are dozens of text boxes.

Comment: What are you doing now manually to fit the text?

Comment: @RichMichaels Go through “shape format” menus: right-click ↑ Enter ↑↑ alt+F.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify all text boxes properties (page by page) by selecting any text box in any page then from **Drawing Tools** hit **Selection Pane**, after that select the first one in the list press <kbd>Shift</kbd> then hit the last text box in that list (or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click on the next text box if there are any shapes among them) now you can adjust text in the boxes as the desired for all the text boxes in the same page. 
This method could apply for single page at once only.